# Error 403 when trying to sign in to Google Game Services in android

Tags: android, code-signing

I'm trying to Sing In using Google Android SDK and I get A lot of errors...
I saw all the post about this and any other errors and still can't figure this out.
I check SH1, Google APIs, Linked my app, checked app_id.

This is my code:

```
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
                .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                .build();

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        System.out.println("Logged in");
    }

@Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (!mIntentInProgress && result.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                startIntentSenderForResult(result.getResolution().getIntentSender(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // The intent was canceled before it was sent.  Return to the default
                // state and attempt to connect to get an updated ConnectionResult.
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, requestCode, intent);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            mIntentInProgress = false;

            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSignedIn() {
        return (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
    }
```

The errors I get:

> 02-21 10:07:18.920  11247-11712/com.google.android.gms E/Volley﹕ [937]
>   a.a: Unexpected response code 403 for
>   https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/me?language=en_US 02-21
>   10:07:18.980  11247-17039/com.google.android.gms
>   E/SignInIntentService﹕ Access Not Configured. The API (Google Play
>   Game Services API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the
>   Google Developers Console to update your configuration.
>       com.google.android.gms.games.h.c.a
>               at com.google.android.gms.games.h.b.a(SourceFile:153)
>               at com.google.android.gms.games.a.bj.d(SourceFile:1683)
>               at com.google.android.gms.games.a.bj.b(SourceFile:610)
>               at com.google.android.gms.games.a.bj.b(SourceFile:585)
>               at com.google.android.gms.games.a.t.d(SourceFile:824)
>               at com.google.android.gms.games.service.w.b(SourceFile:347)
>               at com.google.android.gms.games.service.s.a(SourceFile:47)
>               at com.google.android.gms.games.service.GamesSignInIntentService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:499)
>               at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 02-21 10:07:18.985  17012-17012/com.google.android.gms.ui
>   E/LoadSelfFragment﹕ Unable to sign in - application does not have a
>   registered client ID

I also stuck in loop that goes between `onActivityResult` and `onConnectionFailed`. The error code that I get in `onConnectionFailed` is 4.

Any one knows what could it be?

Comment: Are you running on a device with Google Play services? Are you logged in with your Google account on that device?

Comment: I don't know what it means "running with Google Play Services" but I assume that I am cause I can log-in in other games that uses Google Play Login. Yes I logged in with my google account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
I linked my app with the wrong SHA1... I used some custom key or something like that. I tried to debug it on my device and it didn't work.

The solution was to extract SHA1 from the debug key that located here ->

> C:\Users\.android\debug.keystore

and then link my app with it.

Answer (score 0):

This error is seen when your application has not been linked correctly to your project. Please check that you have linked the SHA1 fingerprint for both your debug and release certificates.

In my case I got this error when I used the Google API console (rather than the google play developer console) to add a second SHA1 fingerprint (release version).

I would suggest removing your liked app in the Developer console and then adding again only using the google play developer console to manage the SHA1 keys. Follow the instructions here:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling

Comment: I saw a discussion that mention debug and release certificates but I couldn't understand the difference... can you explain what each one mean and where can I configure them?

Edit: I already tried to remove all certificates from Google API Console and used only Google Developer Console

Comment: Your debug and release apks are signed with different certificates. In the google play developer console, under Game Services, Linked Apps, you need to complete the process of linking both the SHA1 for your release certificate and your debug certificate.  There is a button labelled 'Link another app'. Also if you have only published to alpha or beta the only accounts that will be able to log in to play services using your app will be the accounts you have added to the testers list and your account that is publishing the app.

Comment: Is it possible to use Google Play Service for Debug and Release at the same time?
How can I get the debug SHA1?
The only way that I know is:
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_03\bin\keytool.exe" -list -v -keystore ____ -alias _______

and I use it on the signed apk that I generate from IntelliJ (so I think this is the release)
If I understood u correctly I need to upload the debug apk as well as the release?

Comment: You don't need to upload your debug apk (in fact the developer console will not allow a debug apk to be uploaded).  You can find the debug keystore on windows in the folder C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.android\debug.keystore. If that does not exist you will have to search for what IntelliJ will use as a debug keystore as I have only used Eclipse and Android Studio.

Comment: I think that I have only one key no debug key or release key. I have a key that ends with .jks
and thats all...